# Sort order of data from Entity Framework

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

Is set of objects obtained with Entity Framework ordered by primary key by default?

UPDATE: In what order table rows are read if there is no 'order by' in query. will they always be in random order? or still sorted by primary key?

Comment: I guess it depends on your database but I wouldn´t rely on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no order** by **default**.

The order of **the retrieved data depends on your DBMS**.

Just profile your database and you will see that the Entity Framework Query has no `Order By` in the SQL-Query.

Comment: i know that there is no 'order by' in query by default. ok, i'll reformulate my question - in what order table rows are read if there is no 'order by' in query. will they always be in random order? or still sorted by primary key?

Comment: thx for reply. In truth i want to know if i need to order by id additionally to get the list sorted in the order the items were inserted.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are ordered by the order of select columns (if your query does not contain orderby)